# What can you do without a deck in the Matrix to help the Decker?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, one-shot, sr5-matrix, hacking

I'm trying to run a quick one-shot for some friends, and upon realizing that we need to figure out how to get some files, we've stopped to read the Matrix section of the book.

I'm a little confused; if they choose to try and hack through the Matrix instead of trying to break into the location to get physical access, can the rest of the party (without decks, but with commlinks) do anything to help?

And if they decide to break in, how do I adjudicate grabbing the files from a physical terminal? Presumably a Hacking dice roll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off of the top of my head? Several things:

- Cast Increase Logic on them to increase their Matrix dicepools, which
  are derived from Logic + relevant skill.
- Cast healing spells on them when they run afoul of Black IC and start
  taking real damage rather than Matrix damage.
- Use stim patches to fix them up if they run afoul of Black IC that's
  dealing Stun damage.
- Stand by to pull the plug on them if they send a signal that they've
  gotten in over their head, and getting dumpshocked is better than
  being killed by IC or having their meatspace location tracked down.
- Shoot the corp security decker in the face to stop them from running surveillance, if they're located in the same location as the runners.

In general, though, the best idea is simply not to run a Decker PC and to just let them take a Decker Contact that can do the Matrix legwork for them with a simple Connection + appropriate skill roll on the Contact's behalf.

Comment: I don't really have a choice for this one-shot,  but I'll try to steer them toward doing things in realspace instead of through the Matrix. They have options. Thanks!